# Modern UI ClusteredBarChart Does Not Exist In XML Namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, charts

I am using Metro charts for creating charts, but when I add chart and debug it says:

> Error: The tag 'ClusteredBarChart' does not exist in XML namespace
>   'clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart'.
>   Line 325 Position 22.

I have already added dll for WPF in reference and added name space as

```
xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
```

I have no clue why it is giving this error?

**EDIT:** 
this is code for adding chart control

```
    <chart:ClusteredBarChart x:Name="barchart1" ChartSubTitle="Population in millions" ChartTitle="Countries by population"> 
    <chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series> 
    <chart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Populations}" SeriesTitle="World largest populations" ValueMember="Count" /> 
    </chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series> 
    </chart:ClusteredBarChart>
```

Comment: this is code for adding chart control  <chart:ClusteredBarChart x:Name="barchart1" ChartSubTitle="Population in millions" ChartTitle="Countries by population">
                        <chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>
                            <chart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Name"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Populations}"
                           SeriesTitle="World largest populations"
                           ValueMember="Count" />

                        </chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>
                    </chart:ClusteredBarChart>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the DLL under the `Binaries/WPF` folder, despite the error message, it will still work. If you download and compile the source code and use the resulting DLL from your compilation, the error message goes away.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication249.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart;assembly=De.TorstenMandelkow.MetroChart"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication249"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MyViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <chart:ClusteredBarChart x:Name="barchart1" 
                             ChartSubTitle="Population in millions" 
                             ChartTitle="Countries by population">
        <chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>
            <chart:ChartSeries DisplayMember="Name" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Populations}" 
                               SeriesTitle="World largest populations" 
                               ValueMember="Count" />
        </chart:ClusteredBarChart.Series>
    </chart:ClusteredBarChart>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bro! Actually source code was in 4.5 framework and my project is in 4.0 framework. But you gave me way to solve this!

Comment: Hey Now another problem, chart does not show up!!! some exception is getting thrown in style, it says 'ChartBase' target type does not match type of element 'ClusteredBarChart'